# O365 Infopath form REST data source

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365, infopath

I cannot get over with an issue related to O365 and an InfoPath form which is having a Data Source calling a REST api.

The case is:

1. In the site where the InfoPath form is I have a list which I'd like to query for a different data based on the rules from the form;
2. I have created a REST data source calling the list REST interface (/_api/web/lists/getbytitle ...)
3. I have followed the steps from the post here and related: http://sympmarc.com/2013/12/23/infopath-2013-forms-on-office365-with-external-rest-datasources/

But still with no success... While trying to query the REST URL InfoPath form keeps telling me that "XML data that is required for this form to function correctly cannot be found." And when I try to edit data connection from the InfoPath application, I'm getting an error that the application cannot open my REST URL and that the file cannot be accessed.

Have anyone got any idea how to solve the issue? For me it really seems like some sort of permissions issue, but I don't know how to solve it.

Regards,
Tomasz